# Не скрывается блок в bootstrap (hidden-md hidden-lg)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть блок с 4 элементами в сетке `bootstrap` которые отличаются по содержанию, а значит и по высоте. [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="feature-item col-lg-3 col-sm-6 wow slideInUp" style="visibility: visible;">
                    <div class="feature-media">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/112x112" width="112" height="112" alt="текст" title="текс">
                    </div>
                    <h4>Текст</h4>
                    <div class="feature-item-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy</div>
                </div>
    <div class="feature-item col-lg-3 col-sm-6 wow slideInUp" style="visibility: visible;">
                    <div class="feature-media">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/112x112" width="112" height="112" alt="текст" title="текс">
                    </div>
                    <h4>Текст</h4>
                    <div class="feature-item-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy</div>
                </div>
    <div class="clearfix hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
    <div class="feature-item col-lg-3 col-sm-6 wow slideInUp" style="visibility: visible;">
                    <div class="feature-media">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/112x112" width="112" height="112" alt="текст" title="текс">
                    </div>
                    <h4>Текст</h4>
                    <div class="feature-item-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply</div>
                </div>
    <div class="feature-item col-lg-3 col-sm-6 wow slideInUp" style="visibility: visible;">
                    <div class="feature-media">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/112x112" width="112" height="112" alt="текст" title="текс">
                    </div>
                    <h4>Текст</h4>
                    <div class="feature-item-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500. Lorem Ipsum has been</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Хочу добиться правильного отображения на всех разрешениях экранов, но элементы соскакивают на следующую строку с пустотами. 
Пробую исправить отображение с помощью

```
<div class="clearfix hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
```

Но, блок почему-то не скрывается на экранах размеров `md` и `lg`
В чем причина и как это исправить?

Comment: `clearfix hidden-md hidden-lg` в вашем примере скрывается при размерах `md` и `lg`. У вас сетка для md не задана и она от col-sm-6, и вроде порядок в бутстрепе обязателен с минимального к максимальному.

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev получилось! ответ ниже

Answer (score -1):

Ха, как интересно, - вот такое изменение в блоках не сработало

```
<div class="feature-item col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 wow slideInUp" style="visibility: visible;">
```

А вот так - дало нужный эффект!

```
<div class="feature-item col-sm-6 col-md-3 wow slideInUp" style="visibility: visible;">
```

Comment: ну и кто минусует верный ответ?